# HTML with CSS for progress bar

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV like this:

```
<div class="prog" style="width:100%">
<div class="prog" style="width:78%">
<div class="prog" style="width:43%">
```

How can i make this div background with gradient to start from 44% of the div. just like the picture. if we put width 43% so just this color #9c45c4 will be shown.. if we put more than 43% the gradient will start.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background-size` to the size of the containing element for the progress bar.

I don't see any "conditional gradient" in the screenshot you provided.

Comment: The gradient is from this #9c45c4 to black (#000000)

Comment: Yes, and as the progress bar's size changes, it reveals more of the gradient. The gradient itself doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Tcndj/2/

I typically use a wrapper div, like in my example.

Comment: So your issue is that the gradient scales with the width of the bar...

How about applying the gradient to the parent div, and using the inner bar as a "mask"? The bar will need to have it's width inverted (25% now becomes 75%). See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tcndj/4/

Comment: but the problem is i have border-radius.. imagine with border radius .. the right side will not have border radius.... http://jsfiddle.net/Tcndj/5/

Comment: In that case...I'd recommend the `background-size` CSS method as described by @Kolink. Only issue is it isn't supported in older browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good easy to use progress bar implementation. I use it whenever I need a progress bar. 
http://www.bram.us/projects/js_bramus/jsprogressbarhandler/#what